# IIS replaces host of links in web page

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

I have an static html file with some links to: `http://example2.com/url`

The html file is hosted in other site: `http://example.com/app/index.html`

If I access the file locally, e.i. in the IIS server. All the links point to the correct Urls (`http://example2.com/url`).  However if I access the site from another machine all the URL links in file index.html are replaced with: `http://example.com/url`

I am sure this error is related to some configuration mistake but currently  I am completely lost.

Any help be will really appreciated

Comment: Short descriptions like this won't lead to any useful follow-ups, as you make readers lost too.

Comment: @LexLi, Ok, would you mind suggesting what more information could I add?

Comment: Too much. It would be necessary to see related IIS settings, as well as Fiddler trace if you know what that is. A better way is to buy a good IIS book and learn it. Don't expect such complex (as you cannot easily describe it) thing to be solved over the internet.